# How do I secure an ASP.NET core 6 web API for use by external clients?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

Currently we have an ASP.NET core 6.0 API hosted in Azure, based on the documentation on azure API management services security, it recommends using a subscription key to secure the API. It also recommends using Azure AD B2C, however it would be impossible to implement that on every client side application since some already run on other authentication frameworks.

Will subscription keys suffice as a secure way of accessing the API or is there another viable way?

Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-api-management?tabs=app-reg-ga

Comment: `impossible to implement that on every client side application since some already run on other authentication frameworks.` that's not relevant. How client applications authenticate their own users has nothing to do with the mechanism they use to connect to third party services. The de-facto standard is to use JWT tokens - applications log into the remote services or a commonly trusted authentication service and receive a JWT token they pass to all API calls. Quite often the login step used OpenID Connect, another standard. The Azure AD B2C you linked to shows that B2C uses JWT tokens itself.

Comment: Azure AD B2C [supports OpenID Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect) so clients can use the same code they already use to connect to other services. Azure AD also has client libraries that make this a lot simpler though

Answer (score 1):

This topic is covered perfectly regarding current best practices in the official ASP.NET Core documentation of Microsoft. You might be especially interested in the "Bearer Token Authentication" method: [Authenticate with bearer tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/secure-net-microservices-web-applications/#authenticate-with-bearer-tokens)